# ¿Cómo puedo crear un servicio con un ejecutable de ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, servicio, dotnetcore, kestrel

les comento lo que estoy realizando y me esta generando algunos contratiempos.
Al publicar un proyecto en ASP.NET core 6, lo publico con destino 'Carpeta', generando un directorio donde se encuentra el código de la aplicación y un .exe como punto de entrada a la misma. Este .exe lo genera el servidor web Kestrel, que es comúnmente usado en proyectos ASP.NET Core.
Lo que quiero hacer es un servicio que ejecute ese .exe, al generarlo satisfactoriamente y querer iniciarlo me marca que tarda demasiado en responder. Pero si yo lo ejecuto por fuera me lo abre normalmente, ya probé cambiarlo de directorio pensando en quizá un tema de permisos. Pero aún no lo puedo solucionar.
Ojala puedan ayudarme y ayudar a alguien más que se encuentre en esta situación. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo despligue en... IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Hace alrededor de un año leí en algún lado que para producción era mejor usar IIS (no pude encontrar la fuente). Mi problema (y creo que el tuyo) es que buscaba una forma que el servidor web se levantara solo antes caídas. Así que mi recomendación es preferir usar `IIS` por sobre `Kestrel`

---

Directamente no puedes convertir el `.exe` generado en un servicio, porque este no implementa los elementos necesario para ello. En otras palabras no puedes usar [SC.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create) que seria lo habitual. Pero si puedes usar software adicional, me parece que el más usado es [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/)

Otra cosa que podría resultar es crear un proyecto del tipo `servicio de windows`, luego en "agregar referencias" referencias la `dll` generada de un proyecto ASP y luego ejecutas el `Main` de esa dll

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        MiProyectoASP.Program.Main(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

}
```

Esto último no lo he probado nunca y no se si funcionará, porque el servicio es un proyecto `.net framework` y el tuyo es `.net core`, pero no pierdes nada con probar